# Retrofit2 Missing XML Declaration in SOAP requests

Tags: android, soap, retrofit

I sent with retrofit2 SoapenvEnvelope created by org.simpleframework.xml to SOAP webservice

My SoapenvEnvelope

```
@Root(name = "soapenv:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
    @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", prefix = "soapenv")
})
public class SoapenvEnvelope {

@Element(name = "soapenv:Header", required = false)
public SoapenvHeader env1header;

@Element(name = "soapenv:Body", required = false)
public EkassaRequestBody env2body;

}
```

My retrofit2 interface

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/soap+xml", "Accept-Charset: utf-8"})
@POST("soap/services/v2")
Observable<EkassaResponseEnvelope> getRegisterReceiptEkassa(@Body SoapenvEnvelope requestEnvelope);
```

My request in Logging HTTP is

[image]

How can I add XML declaration before soapenv:Envelope tag ?

[image]